# Nested Form missing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, form-for

I am having a problem getting the params of a nested form in the following case:

I have these 3 nested **models**:

Meeting:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :participants
end
```

Participant:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :meeting
 has_many :connections
end
```

and Connection:

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :participant, :foreign_key => 'connected_participant_id'
end
```

And these **routes**:

```
resources :meetings do
    resources :participants
end

resources :participants do
    resources :connections
end
```

I succesfully made a form to create participants and add them directly to a meeting with something like this:

In the  **view > meeting/show**:

```
= link_to 'Add current user to meeting', new_meeting_participant_url(@meeting)
```

In the **view > participant/new**:

```
= form_for [@meeting, @participant] do |p|
    *form details*
```

When creating i successfully receive params[:meeting_id], however when doing the same when creating a connection between participants with the following configurations I don't get the params I need

in the **same view > meeting/show**:

```
- @meeting.participants.each do |participant|
    = link_to new_participant_connection_url(participant)
```

and again the form **view > connection/new**:

```
= form_for [@participant, @connection] do |c|
```

by debugging i noticed the needed params[:participant_id] are not set.

Can anyone please help me with my problem? I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at [ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it as the first in the morning, and when i can find a solution i'll post as an answer to my question.